# why disqus/facebook have a seperate javascript file hosted for every website when integrating them to your website

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, disqus

DISQUSS js code

```
     */* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

Facebook JavaScript code

```
(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```

why disqus/facebook have a seperate javascript file hosted for every website e.g

```
    dsq.src = 'http://work4sale.disqus.com/embed.js'; // disqus
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; // facebook
```

why they cannot have one universal js file for every website. while integrating them to your website.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has dozens of scripts for you to use on your site: like button, comments, etc. - each one being 10-15 KB or so... just guessing.  Probably 3-4 KB gzipped.

So when you need a like button, copy the like button script and use it on your site.  If you want comments, copy the comments script and use it on your site.

If facebook were to provide one single all-inclusive script to include on your site, that script could easily be hundreds of kilobytes when you only need the functionality of about 10-15 kilobytes.  Now, you multiply... lets say 200 KB by millions of requests per minute, and you are talking about gigabytes (possibly terabytes) of unnecessary bandwidth a minute.  Now I know this might not matter much to you and your little mom and pop websites, but this translates into millions of dollars of bandwidth a year for facebook.

Comment: My friend i am saying that in disqus comment system they have the same embed.js file replicated on every website regardless of different plugin i.e Like, comment, share etc. plugin e.g

 http://website1.disqus.com/embed.js
or
 http://website2.disqus.com/embed.js // same js file but different URL
or
 http://website2.disqus.com/embed.js // same js but different URL

why they cannot have the below universal path
    http://all-website.disqus.com/embed.js 
same universal js URL for each and every website. why hosting the same js file on different sub domains for each website